# Are "enum class" members instantiated immediately or later when used?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this one

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
  enum class X {
    V = T()
  };
};
```

For member classes and member functions, C++11 (and C++03) won't instantiate their definition unless we use them in a way that requires their definition. Is this true for `enum class`?

```
// valid?
A<std::string> a;
```

Unfortunately, I can't check compilers, since C++11 is just out of the door and everything isn't reliable yet, it seems.

Comment: I don't think `A<std::string> a;` is valid unless `std::string` can be implicitly converted to `int`. But then again...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think so. 14.7.1/1

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit
>   instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions or default arguments, of [...] scoped member enumerations

Comment: Thanks! Reported as http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10044 and http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49224 .